# Discuss our Work with Juan?

Tags: traducción

My understanding is that "work" is a lot more versatile than "trabajar."  *Trabajar* is used to describe physical actions, such as

> The man is working. -- El hombre está trabajando.

But what if I wanted to use work as a noun, such as saying "I would like have a meeting to share our work with Juan", would it be appropriate to use *trabajo* here, as in:

> Reunión para hablar de nuestro trabajo con Juan?

Comment: This can depend on which sense of "work" you mean. If you mean "I would like to have a meeting to share our work (of art) with Juan" you might use "obra". If you mean "so we can share in the labor of working" you might say "labor", etc.

Comment: More along the line's of Juan's work (ie this project that Juan worked on, Juan's work")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you got it right. You can use `trabajo` in the context of

> Me gustaría tener una reunión para hablar de nuestro **trabajo** con Juan?  <sub>I would like have a meeting to share our **work** with Juan</sub>

`Trabajo` is the action of doing some work, its result, or even the job itself. You can also use "empleo" for "job", but at least in Spain people favor `trabajo` to describe a job.

> Me gustaría tener una reunión para explicarle a Juan en qué consiste su nuevo **trabajo**  <sub>I would like have a meeting to explain Juan in what consists his new **job**</sub>

`Trabajar` is a verb. You are right when you say it describes the action of doing work, but it doesn't need to be *physical* work.

> Finalmente he encontrado un nuevo trabajo (empleo)
>
> Este documento es mi trabajo de fin de carrera
>
> Cuidar de un bebé es mucho trabajo
>
> Te felicito. Has hecho un buen trabajo con este proyecto.

Answer (score 1):

If the meeting is for talk about **Juan's job** *(work position or some stuff related to him)* the translation would be:

> *Me gustaría tener una reunión para compartir nuestro trabajo con Juan.*

Hence *IMO*, the word *trabajo* works as a noun here too.